# Undefined variable при загрузке файла на сервер

Tags: php, sql-server

Проблема в следующем, есть форма, я добавляю туда возможность добавить файл. При подтверждении формы ссылка на файл должна записываться в бд, для построения журнала. Затык в следующем: при сохранении добавленного файла получаю PHP Notice.

```
PHP Notice: Undefined variable: result_file on line 79
```

Код вот такой :

```
if(isset($_FILES["filename"])) {
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"])) {
    $path = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $base = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $name = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s.").$ext; //переименовываем файл

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "./images/eis/".$name);

   $result_file = '<br><a href="/images/eis/' . $name .'">' . $name . '</a>';}
 else {$result_file = null;}

   $tsql =sprintf("update journal set result_file='%s' where id = '%d'", $result_file, $jid)
```

Есть подозрение, что sprintf не смог взять $result_file из предыдущего условия. Тогда встаёт вопрос как написать этот кусок кода, чтобы ссылка на файл записывалась в бд.

Comment: А зачем вставлять NULL в БД?

Comment: Даже если убрать else->null, то всё равно в бд записывается пустота, а сам сайт выдает php notice

Answer (score 1):

sprintf в вашем случае не вставляет result_file потому что в строке есть html теги, это легко проверить

```
$tsql =sprintf("update journal set result_file='%s' where id = '%d'", $result_file, $jid)
echo $tsql;
```

Comment: Тут дело не в том, что он не вставляет result_file. Дело в том, что php не может обнаружить переменную, как я понял.